# How I enable my Google drive which show disable in my personal mi phone?

Tags: 7.0-nougat

[image]
I update my mi phone yesterday for android 7.0 nougat  version. But I see in my personal phone the google drive is disabled. Now I want to enable my google drive for back up items. How can I do ? Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there is an issue with Android Nougat. Some of the discussions in Forums like [here](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/drive/FLCIN88EdeM;context-place=topicsearchin/drive/category$3Aandroid%7Csort:relevance%7Cspell:false) suggest the issue would be fixed by September 21. You can also email the Google Team regarding the same. I don't believe hard reset will also help you.